# casting between C# derived classes, in F#

Tags: f#

I have two types coming from a C# lib:

one is defined like this (only signatures):

```
public class CallResult<T>: CallResult
{
    public CallResult([AllowNull]T data, Error? error): base(error)
    public static implicit operator bool(CallResult<T> obj)
    public bool GetResultOrError([MaybeNullWhen(false)] out T data, [NotNullWhen(false)] out Error? error)
    public new static WebCallResult<T> CreateErrorResult(Error error)
}
```

and the second one derives from it:

```
public class WebCallResult<T>: CallResult<T>
{
    public HttpStatusCode? ResponseStatusCode { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>>? ResponseHeaders { get; set; }
    public WebCallResult(HttpStatusCode? code, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>>? responseHeaders, [AllowNull] T data, Error? error): base(data, error)
    public WebCallResult(WebCallResult<T> callResult): base(callResult.Data, callResult.Error)
    public static WebCallResult<T> CreateFrom<Y>(WebCallResult<Y> source) where Y : T
    public static WebCallResult<T> CreateErrorResult(HttpStatusCode? code, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>>? responseHeaders, Error error)
}
```

and they both come from:

```
public class CallResult
{
    public Error? Error { get; internal set; }
    public bool Success => Error == null;
    public CallResult(Error? error)
    public static implicit operator bool(CallResult obj)
    public static WebCallResult CreateErrorResult(Error error)
}
```

Some api calls return a CallResult, others return a WebCallResult.

Right now I use two times the same code to handle it:

```
// turn a webcall result into a Result object
let processResultWeb (applyOnOk: 'a -> 'b) (result: WebCallResult<'a>) =
    match result.Success with
    | true ->  Result.Ok (applyOnOk result.Data)
    | false -> Result.Error (decodeError result.Error)

// turn a webcall result into a Result object
let processResult (applyOnOk: 'a -> 'b) (result: CallResult<'a>) =
    match result.Success with
    | true ->  Result.Ok (applyOnOk result.Data)
    | false -> Result.Error (decodeError result.Error)
```

Which doesn't really make sense since it's the same code and I'm only caring about the data from the base class (CallResult).

So I would like to cast both types to the base class:

```
let a: WebCallResult = ...
let r = a :> CallResult
```

but this results in a compiler error:

> [FS0001] The type 'CallResult' is not compatible with the type 'WebCallResult<'a>'

how can I check the result for both types by just accessing the fields from their base class, but using the same generic type.

Edit:
the source code of the classes is here: https://pastebin.com/mrw5W7xk

The issue is that I want to go from:

```
WebCallResult<'a'> to CallResult<'a>
```

and the generic seems to be the issue.

Comment: Something doesn't seem right to me. If `WebCallResult<T>` is derived from `CallResult`, then you should be able to cast from derived class to base class with no problem.

Comment: that's my thought too; I'm wondering if the issue could be the generic; I added a link with the whole source in the question.

Comment: Try to cast to `CallResult<_>` and then further to `CallResult`. I'm thinking that since generics is involved, perhaps doing it in two steps can work, but it's just a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your code, I'm able to cast with no problem, even with generics. Here's an example:

```
let foo x =
    WebCallResult<_>(System.Nullable(), Array.empty, x, Error())

let a : WebCallResult<int> = foo 3
let r = a :> CallResult<_>

let b : WebCallResult<string> = foo "str"
let q = b :> CallResult<_>
```

Comment: the missing part on my end was the <_>, I was not including that

Comment: Ah, I see. Then my comment on the Q isn't relevant either.